# Recognize and get city from an unstructured text

Tags: java, nlp

I have sample texts as below numbered :

```
1)';Roy\'\'s Chalet, sears road,Green woods;Street avenue;Arlington;Texas;United States;'
2)';PLOT NO. A-10, Seras -1, Green woods woods;PARK,;Arlington;Texas;United States;'
3)';Seras tampon woods avenue park green AS IN;Wallet Hall;St Ann ROAD Arlington Texas;United States;'.
```

I need a way to recognize city "Arlington" from each text.
There are million of records with such texts and the cities embedded in text . What is the best way to achieve this in java.

Would nlp like technique help here ?.

Answer (score 3):

A list of place names is called a "gazetteer". Here is one with a lot of cities in the US and other countries (there are others, just google for "gazetteer" or "list of cities in the US": http://www.fallingrain.com/world/index.html

You could crawl the website and store the list of city names in a file. Then your program could read them into an appropriate data structure and check the words in each line for membership. Watch out for city names that consist of multiple words, like "San Francisco".

From a more general NLP perspective, you're looking for a "named entity recognizer". This is a system which attempts to tag the words in your string as either person names or location names. This should solve your problem too, at the expense of including someone else's library into your project and figuring out how to use it. One NE recognizer that is used a lot is from the Stanford NLP tools, http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.html